# Getting average of top 30% of the values in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that lists bunch of numbers. How can I select the average of top 30% of the values in one column:

```
'Values'
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

so, the top 30% is '10, 9, 8' and the average is (10+9+8)/3 = 9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any version of excel you can use either a SUMIF/COUNTIF along the same lines as Sean's suggestion, i.e.

`=SUMIF(A1:A10,">"&PERCENTILE(A1:A10,0.7))/COUNTIF(A1:A10,">"&PERCENTILE(A1:A10,0.7))`

or a shorter "array formula"

`=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A10>PERCENTILE(A1:A10,0.7),A1:A10))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

These should all give identical results

Answer (score 6):

If you are using excel 2007 or newer, `=AVERAGEIF(A2:A10,">"&PERCENTILE(A2:A10,0.7))`

Answer (score 1):

Without using VBA:

Putting data into column A.

Create this intermediate column B:

```
    B1=IF(RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$10)<=30*COUNT($A$1:$A$10)/(100), A1,0)
    B2=IF(RANK(A2, ...
```

Then Average this column with:

```
    =AVERAGEIF(B1:B10,">0")
```

For your given example you get 9.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this without formulas by including a column title and choosing:

*Data > Filter > Number Filter > Top 10...(Top 30 Percent)*

Highlight the column to see sum, average, count, max. (Right-click the status bar and select "average" if not displayed.)

If you want the result of the filtered average in a cell you can use `=SUBTOTAL(1,A2:A11)`