# Average of top 10 values in a row, treating empty cells as ones

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a row in excel consisting of `n` cells (in fact `n=12`). Some of these cells have numerical values, some may be empty. I want to find the average of the top `m` cells in the row (in fact `m=10`), treating the empty cells as if they contained 1s.

(The context for this is that I want to compute the average grades of some students whose homework I grade, and this is the formula used in the course. The empty cells correspond to homeworks which were not handed in, but I would like to keep the distinction between homeworks graded 1 and those missing.)

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried already and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: "Top" cells in a "row"? Can you clarify?

Comment: I am very much new to excel; I have looked up [different excel averaging functions](http://www.contextures.com/excelaveragefunctions.html) and [an earlier question on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852999/getting-average-of-top-30-of-the-values-in-one-column) but I don't see how any of these things help me. I suppose I could do it the hard way and find how to replace values in an excel array (list?), sort it, remove the lower two values; but excel has a lot of builtin power, so there should be a "shortcut".

Comment: @XORLX, I mean the cells with the highest (numerical) value.

Comment: And what if the number of cells containing numerics is less than m?

Comment: I want to treat the empty cells as if they contain 1s. Thus, all `n` cells are treated as if they contain numerical values. (In fact, the lowest numeric value that may appear in a cell is 1, if it helps.) I just don't want to actually add the numeric values because it is useful to keep the cells blank for purposes other than computing the average final grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on data in `A1:L1`, **array formula****:

`=AVERAGE(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:L1),A1:L1,1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This looks like what I want, but when I try to enter it I get an error message, "the formula you typed contains an error". The only thing I changed was replacing both instances of A1:L1 with B2:M2 (which is the relevant range).

Comment: Does your system use the comma or semicolon as argument separator in formulas?

Comment: Interesting. You mean it accepts the commas in the array constant? I would've thought you'd have to use either "\" or ";" (or perhaps even ".").

Comment: I changed all commas into semicolons and that did the trick. This version of excel is set to Dutch (I suppose) so that the comma is the decimal separator. (So, no, it does not accept commas in the array constant either.)

Comment: Ah, I see. You changed them everywhere! Lucky you! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the 12 items in cells **B1** thru **M1**.  In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1="",1,B1)
```

and copy across.  In **A1** enter:

```
=LARGE($B$2:$M$2,ROWS($1:1))
```

and copy down.  Now to get the average of the top 4 grades, simply pick a cell and use:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A4)
```

[image]

To get the top 5, use `=AVERAGE(A1:A5)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be done slightly less complicated than arrays, by just splitting the average into its parts, the sum and the division.

```
=(sum(B2:K2)+countif(B2:K2,0))/10
```

This is for scores horizontally starting in the B2 row. You sum the scores, then count the zeroes (which is what you want to add to the sum). Then divide by m.

Comment: This only solves half of the problem; the other aspect of it is that you do not want to take the average of all values but only of the top 10 out of 12.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant literally "the top" 10. I was assuming you had sorted descending, which would make the simple sum&count work.